# finding a specific element based on keyword and push to array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all input elements, and based on the id of the elements I want to search the id to match a specific keyword. If a match is found I want put the element in the array `targetNodse`. The variable `nodes` contains all the inputs, and when I log the array I get `[-1, -1, 0, 0]` which tells me it found the specific input elements with the keyword `survey-answer`. But how do I access the elements attributes rather than just telling me it found it?

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="poll-answer-8234" name="poll_430" value="8234">
<input type="radio" id="poll-answer-9234" name="poll_430" value="9234">  
<input type="radio" id="survey-answer-7866" name="poll_430" value="7866">
<input type="radio" id="survey-answer-8998" name="poll_430" value="8998">
```

**JS**

```
var targetNodes, nodes, count;

targetNodes = [];

nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (count = 0; count < nodes.length; count++) {
    node = nodes[count].id.indexOf("survey-answer");
    targetNodes.push(node);
}

console.log(targetNodes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push the node into the array instead of the result of the `indexOf` call:

```
for (count = 0; count < nodes.length; count++) {
  var node = nodes[count].id.indexOf("survey-answer");
  if (node != -1) {
    targetNodes.push(nodes[count]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
var targetNodes, nodes, count;

targetNodes = [];

nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (count = 0; count < nodes.length; count++) {
    node = nodes[count].id.indexOf("survey-answer");
    if (node == 0)
      targetNodes.push(nodes[count]);
}

alert(targetNodes);
```

Here targetNodes array contains input Objects.

If you want to access value of input tags then in the `IF` condition, set as follows

```
if (node == 0)
  targetNodes.push(nodes[count].value);
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/QR9Ry/)** and another **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/QR9Ry/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetNodes, nodes, count;

targetNodes = [];

nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (count = 0; count < nodes.length; count++)
{
    node = nodes[count].id.indexOf("survey-answer");

    if (node != -1)
    {
        targetNodes.push(nodes[count]);
    }
}

for (count = 0; count < targetNodes.length; count++)
{ 
      alert("id: " + targetNodes[count].id +
            ", name: " + targetNodes[count].name + 
            ", value: " + targetNodes[count].value);
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle to test this out: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/YwLEu/1/